# How to plot CDF plot based on two selected pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

## Background

I have a dataframe containing three variables:

- city:  the city names within China.
- pop:   the population number of the corresponding city.
- conc:  the concentration of ambient pollutant of the corresponding city.

I want to investigate the cumulative distribution of the concentration by the population.

The sample figure is shown like this:

[image]

The sample dataset is uploaded [here](https://ufile.io/4gcrs)

## My solution

```
df = pd.read_csv("./data/test.csv",)    
df = df[df.columns[1:]]
df = df.sort_values(by=['pm25'],ascending=False)
df = df.reset_index()

x_ = df['pm25'].values
y_ = []
for i in range(0,len(df)-1,1):
    y_.append(df['pop'].iloc[:i+1].sum()/df['pop'].sum())
y_.append(1.0)
plt.plot(x_,y_)
```

[image]

### 1.

*Any better method is highly appreciated!*

### 2.

*Also, how to make the curve smooth as the first plot?*

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the loop by a use of [`pd.Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html):

```
y_ = df.pop.cumsum() / df.pop.sum()
```

For smoothing, you can use [`pd.Series.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html):

```
plot(x_, y_.rolling(3).mean())
```

which applies a low pass filter (of length 3). You should consider if that is what you want, however - your plot seems correct.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. `Loop` is  the  dumbest way, indeed.